# Can't get a List of objects from a model in Razor CSHTML page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, c#-4.0, razor-pages

This is my first time posting to Stack Overflow. So forgive me if I am not asking the question properly.

I have created a Razor page (in 4.72) wherein the Employer model has a List of Employee models embedded into the Employer model as well. I have Razor page with the Employer information on top and entries for multiple employees below. When submitting the page to create the employer, and employees,  I am passing the Employer model into Action Result .  But for some reason the List of Employees doesn't come with the Employer model.

The Employer Model and it's values comes over just fine., but not Employees.

My Razor page:

```
@model FraudReports.Models.FraudReportEmployer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateEmployee";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FEIN, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FEIN, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FEIN, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- More form Employer fields here -->
        <!-- Start list of Employees here (Number of Employees could vary, using 5 entries for now. )-->

        @{
            for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                <hr />
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FraudReportEmployees[i].FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FraudReportEmployees[i].FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FraudReportEmployees[i].FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FraudReportEmployees[i].MI, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FraudReportEmployees[i].MI, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FraudReportEmployees[i].MI, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- More form Employee fields here -->


            }

            <!-- End list of Employee fields here -->


        }






        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

My Action method:

```
      public ActionResult CreateEmployee(FraudReportEmployer fraudReportEmployer)
        {
        List<FraudReportEmployee> FraudReportEmployees = fraudReportEmployer.FraudReportEmployees;

        
! There are values in Employer model but not the Employee List inside.

        .
        .
         return View();
        }
```

The Employer Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FraudReports.Models
{
    public class FraudReportEmployer
    {

        public string EmployerName { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }

        public string ContactPhone { get; set; }

        public string ContactEmail { get; set; }

        ....


        public List<FraudReportEmployee> FraudReportEmployees { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Employee MOdel:

```
namespace FraudReports.Models
{
    public class FraudReportEmployee
    {
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MI { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to ensure that list of employees is populated, that's all. It clearly isn't. So how is the Employer model loaded?

Comment: It is suppose to be loaded in my Razor page.

Comment: Whoops.   It is suppose to be loaded in my Razor page.   See the code up at top.   It should be coming over in the form submit.  the upper portion (employer fields are coming over but the List of employees is not.

Comment: I don't think its clear enough from your code. You seem to have a loop that populates employees. So far so good. Is that code ever ran?

Comment: @user1549746: How much elements in the `FraudReportEmployees` list when you are passing the data model to the view  and why you want to edit only the second element in the list? Can you include code of the the `form` block to the post, please?

Comment: Let me put in more code. Hang on.

Comment: Yes the code has been ran.  I see values come over with Employer model, but  I don't see any values for the Employee List

Answer (score 0):

The indexing should be started from `0`, like

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

When the first element in the collection is missing the MVC can't bind the collection elements properly.

Comment: That did it! I'm done pounding my head against a rock. Thanks, Jackdaw.